# Only keep active and has-child classes on navigation

Tags: php, wordpress

Using the following:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    return in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ? ['nav-active'] : [];   
}
```

I am currently removing all classes and just adding 'nav-active' however I'd also like to keep the 'has-child' class but don't know how to modify this to not remove the has-child class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in separate steps, add the classes to an array, and return that in the end.

```
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
  $returnClasses = [];
  if(in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
    $returnClasses[] = 'nav-active';
  } 
  if(in_array('has-child', $classes)) {
    $returnClasses[] = 'has-child';
  }
  return $returnClasses;
}
```